# ViewPoint is not consistent

Tags: export, graphics3d

I copied and tried an example from the documentation of "POV" format:

```
rp = RegionPlot3D[(x^2 + y^4 + z^2) - (x^3 + y^2 + z) > 1/2, 
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]
```

Then I checked the options and I got

```
In[1]:= Options[rp, ViewPoint]
Out[1]= {ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}}
```

However, when I export the plot to POV format, I got

```
In[2]:= ExportString[rp, "POV"]
Out[2]:= /*Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com*/
/*Header*/
#default {pigment {color rgb 1} }

/*AmbientLight*/
#default {finish {ambient color rgb <1, 1, 1>} }

/*ViewPoint*/
camera {
 location <2.6, -4.8, 4.>
 direction <-2.6, 4.8, -4.>
 up <0, 0, 2.8284271247461903>
 right <3.7618080759124335, 0, 0>
 sky <0., 0., 1.>
 look_at <0., 0., 0.>
}
...
```

Why is there a two-fold difference between the camera location and the viewpoint?